# Why do we remove the file handles before pickling a class?

Tags: python

I was checking a YouTube video [from here](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjPnNaa76rJAhUNI44KHQlLDDYQtwIIHDAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DCSsByV7C3mg&usg=AFQjCNHmL-ApMLUYWIbeNWeecdn8utCCgw&sig2=hMvDaPLioWnleLTFf4T9jg&bvm=bv.108194040,d.c2E)

This guy was using `__getstate__` and `__setstate__` methods to remove the file handlers `(self.file)` from the object's `__dict__` to alter it default behavior before he Pickle the class.

But **Why this is necessary? Why I would remove file handlers before I pickle any Class ?**

Sorry in advance if I am missing some important point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`file` objects aren't pickle-able. Look at the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) to see what kind of objects are pickle-able.

You can also try it out:

```
import pickle
with open(<file-path>) as f:
    pickle.dumps(f)
```

throws `TypeError: can't pickle file objects`